# Predicate logic - Symbolizing sentences

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

**K_ = _ is a Kiwi, M_ = _ is a Moa, F_ = _is flightless**

**If something is a moa only if it's flightless then if all kiwis are flightless, some kiwis are moas.**

$$A_x( (M_x \to F_x) \to ( A_x(K_x \ \& \ F_x) \to E_x(K_x \  \& \ M_x) )$$

**a = Anja P_ = _ is a philosopher W_ = _ is wise**

**If all philosophers are wise, then Anja is a philosopher iff she's wise.**

$$A_xP_x \to (P_a \leftrightarrow W_a)$$

**H_ = _is a Historian**

**If only historians are wise and no philosophers are wise then no historians are philosophers.**

$$A_x( (H_x \ \& \ W_x) \ \& \ (P_x \to \ \backsim W_x)) \to (H_x \to \ \backsim P_x) )$$

*Are these symbolizations correct? Thanks in advance! :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two are close!

First one:

$$\forall x( (Mx \rightarrow Fx)\color{red}{)} \rightarrow ( \forall x(Kx \color{red}{\rightarrow} Fx) \rightarrow \exists x(Kx \land Mx) )$$

... actually, rather than adding a close parenthesis, you can just remove the first open parenthesis:

$$\forall x( Mx \rightarrow Fx) \rightarrow ( \forall x(Kx \rightarrow Fx) \rightarrow \exists x(Kx \land Mx) )$$

Second one:

$$\forall x (Px \color{red}{\rightarrow Wx)} \rightarrow (Pa \leftrightarrow Wa)$$

For the third one:

Notice that this is a conditional statement .. so you need a quantifier for the antecedent, but also a quantifier for the consequent ... try again!

Comment: For the first one, why is there a conditional? Doesn't "All kiwis are fightless" also mean "All x are kiwi and all x are fightless"?

Comment: @AmandaO No. If you use an $\land$, then you are saying 'Everything is a kiwi and everything is flightless'.  So, if you and I would be part of the domain, then you and I would be kiwis and flightless as well. ... which is clearly not what you want: we want the kiwis to be flightless, but we don't want to make any claims about everything that's not a kiwi. So, we say: '*if* something is a kiwi, *then* we have something to say about it, ... which is that it is flightless'

Comment: @AmandaO Sure!  Did you retry the third one yet? Oh, and please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting those formulas ... makes for easier reading!

Comment: I did i think that's how it goes:                                                                
∀x( (Hx → Wx)  ∧ (Px → ¬Wx) ) →  ∀x(Hx  → ¬Px)